Error streamlit al usar st.rerun en la nueva versión 1.37
estoy usando streamlit junto con flask en el lenguaje python, el problema es que a partir de la version 1.37 ya no funciona st.experimental_rerun(), y solo funciona st.rerun(), pero al usar rerun me da este error cuando se ejecuta:
RerunData(query_string='link...', is_fragment_scoped_rerun=True)

¿Alguien sabe porque?, he estado mirando en foros y la guia oficial y no he encontrado nada en esta ultima versión, ya que esta versión lleva poco tiempo salida.
Si alguien le ha pasado lo mismo y lo ha solucionado se lo agradecería.

Al final se ha solventado el problema, por lo visto la versión 1.37.0 tenia un bug con st.rerun() y que en la versión 1.37.1 se ha solventado.
